# Prove that $G(B\cap C)=G(B)\cap G(C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let G be a graph and let B be a subclass of the domain of G. We use the symbol G(B) to designate
the class $$G(B)=\{y\mid \exists x\in B\ \text{such that} \ (x,y)\in G\} $$.

The one way containment is pretty straightforward.

But for the coming one, we take $ y \in G (B) \cap G (C) $, then $ y \in G (B) $ and $ y \in G (C) $. Then, there exists $ x \in B $ such that $ (x, y) \in G $, and there exists $ z \in C $, such that $ (z, y) \in G $, to get that $ y \in G (B \cap C) $ would have to guarantee that $ z = x $, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This identity doesn't hold. Define $G = \{(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)\}$. Then for $A = \{0, 1\}$ and $B = \{0, 2\}$, we see that $G(A) = G(B) = \{0, 1\}$ but $G(A \cap B) = G(\{0\}) = \{0\}$.